# Facebook account kit verification not working properly

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit, facebook-account-kit

I have implemented Facebook Account Kit for mobile verification. I called account kit activity like-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, AccountKitActivity.class);
AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
    new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
        LoginType.PHONE,
        AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN);

// ... perform additional configuration ...
configurationBuilder.setReadPhoneStateEnabled(true);
configurationBuilder.setReceiveSMS(true);
intent.putExtra(
    AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
    configurationBuilder.build());
startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Required permissions are granted before going to `AccountKitActivity` if android OS is above Lollipop.

It reads mobile number then when I click "next" button, it is showing attached image ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHT7n.png)) only though I am receiving code SMS from account kit. Why this is happening and how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in panel settings.
"Require App Secret" option should remain turned off.

Answer (score 0):

> What Android version are you using? For M+ you'll need to also request the permission via code (requestPermissions(new String[]{ permission }, requestCode);).

```
AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
            new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(LoginType.PHONE
                    , AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN);
```

// Add these code
 configurationBuilder.setReadPhoneStateEnabled(true);
 configurationBuilder.setReceiveSMS(true);

> and give permission in manifest as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```